# changing innerHTML of child element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change my icon from expand_more to expand_less in following code

```
<li class="dropdown-bt" onclick="dropdown('content');">
    <a>dropdown-content <i class="material-icons">expand_more</i></a>
</li>
```

I am going to use same code multiple times so it would be better to using function multiple times. I thought of using ID for every piece of code but it would be to hectic. So I want to write single function do it but I don't know how, so please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One would usually set a class for that, and use class selector within Javascript. What have you tried so far? [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an object event as a parameter, say `e` to your `dropdown()` and use the **[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property to retrieve the current element content, check it's value and replace the content with another text content like this:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("dropdownBt");

function dropdown(e) {
  var innerText = e.target.children[0];
  
  if(innerText.textContent == "expand_more") {
   innerText.textContent = "expand_less";
  } else {
    innerText.textContent = "expand_more";
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', dropdown);
```

```html
<li class="dropdown-bt" id="dropdownBt"><a>dropdown-content <i class="material-icons">expand_more</i></a></li>
```